# Run django application (Python 2.7.18) in mac m1 environment

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am having issue running django application running in python 2.7.18 version. I have tried everything but numpy and pandas are not being installed. Due to which I am unable to run the project.
I tried building docker image as well. In that as well I am getting errors.
Please help me out.